# How can I add a blank row at the end of this nested foreach? - Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table of game schedules.  In my controller I am doing this;

```
    $schedule = Schedule::where('season', '=', $season->id)
    ->where('date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->get();

    foreach ($schedule as $item) {
        $date = new Carbon($item['date']);
        $months[$date->format("F Y")][] = $item;
    }
```

This allows me to then do this in my blade view;

```
    @foreach ($months as $month => $items)
        <tr style="background-color: rgba(101, 101, 101, 0.4);">
           <td colspan="5">
             <strong>{{ $month }}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($items as $item)
          <tr>
            <td width="20%">{{ date('D, M j', strtotime ($item['date'])) }}/td>
            <td width="20%">{{ $item['time'] }}</td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="{{ url('team', $item['home_team_id']) }}">{{ $item['home_team'] }}</a></td>
            <td width="25%"><a href="{{ url('team', $item['away_team_id']) }}">{{ $item['away_team'] }}</a></td>
            <td width="10%"><a href="gamesheet/{{ $item['id'] }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
         @endforeach
      @endforeach
```

So far so good in that this grabs the month and creates a distinct row with the month as a heading.

Now, I would like to try to do the same with each week.  To get something like this;

```
November 2016
Mon Nov 7 7:00PM Team A   Team B
Mon Nov 7 8:00PM Team C   Team D
<empty row here>
Mon Nov 14 7:00PM Team D Team A
Mon Nov 14 8:00PM Team B Team C
<empty row here>
```

I have tried defining a week array in my controller like this;

```
$weeks[$date->format("M j")][] = $item;
```

But it needs to also end the loop when the month changes.
Any ideas?  Should I be trying to do a further loop in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using an `if` statement inside the `foreach` loop.

You just want to add this at the end of your nested `foreach` loop:

```
@if ($item == end($items))
  <tr></tr>
@endif
```

Which will check if the current `$item` is the last item in `$items`.

Something like this should get you most of the way there:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">{{ date('D, M j', strtotime ($item['date'])) }}/td>
    <td width="20%">{{ $item['time'] }}</td>
    <td width="25%"><a href="{{ url('team', $item['home_team_id']) }}">{{ $item['home_team'] }}</a></td>
    <td width="25%"><a href="{{ url('team', $item['away_team_id']) }}">{{ $item['away_team'] }}</a></td>
    <td width="10%"><a href="gamesheet/{{ $item['id'] }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
  @if ($item == end($items))
  <tr></tr>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Although looking at your current `foreach` loops you would likely end up with this:

```
November 2016
Mon Nov 7 7:00PM Team A   Team B
Mon Nov 7 8:00PM Team C   Team D
Mon Nov 14 7:00PM Team D Team A
Mon Nov 14 8:00PM Team B Team C
<empty row here>
```

So if you can just break the foreach loop down further by date then you could achieve what you're after with this method.